# How i can bring below report in one query in sql ? Is there a way to bring both date of data in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When i run query on (@Date From '2018-06-01') and( @Date To='2018-06-01')

```html
DateFrom Opening Qty In Quantity Out Quantity Closing Qty  For Billing
2018-06-01  1556        802.              0.             2358.        1556
```

When I change  (@Date From '2018-06-02') and( @Date To='2018-06-02')
Similarly when i change more date Yesterday closing become Opening of date which i put.

```html
Date    Opening Qty In Quantity Out Quantity Closing Qty For Billing
2018-06-02 2358    1443             1095         2706 2358
```

```html
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Temp')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Temp

Declare @DateFrom DateTime
Set @DateFrom='2018-06-01'
Declare @DateTo DateTime
Set @DateTo='2018-06-01'

Select @DateFrom Date,
 case when cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6))>0 and ILE.[Posting Date] between @DateFrom and @DateTo 
 then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [In Quantity],
case when cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6))<0 and ILE.[Posting Date] between @DateFrom and @DateTo 
then -cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Out Quantity],
(select SUM(ILE1.[Quantity]) from [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] as ILE1 where ILE1.[Entry No_]=ILE.[Entry No_] and ILE1.[Item No_]=ILE.[Item No_]
and ILE1.[Document No_]=ILE.[Document No_] and ILE1.[Posting Date]<@DateFrom) as [Opening Qty],
(select SUM(ILE1.[Quantity]) from [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] as ILE1 where ILE1.[Entry No_]=ILE.[Entry No_] and ILE1.[Item No_]=ILE.[Item No_]
and ILE1.[Document No_]=ILE.[Document No_] and ILE.[Posting Date]<=@DateTo) as [Closing Qty],ILE.[Posting Date][Posting Date],
ILE.[Item No_] Product,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY [Item No_] Order by ILE.[Posting Date]) Row_Num
into #Temp
 from [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry]ILE where ILE.[Posting Date]<=@DateTo and  ILE.[Primary Customer No_]in('MMBP000094 ') 
 
  Select
  Date
  ,Sum([Opening Qty])[Opening Qty],
   Sum([In Quantity])[In Quantity],
   Sum([Out Quantity])[Out Quantity],
   Sum([Closing Qty])[Closing Qty],Sum([Opening Qty]+[In Quantity])[For Billing] 
   from #Temp Group by Date
```

```html
I want result like this 
Date       Opening   In     Out  Closing
01-06-18  1556   802      0     2358
02-06-18  2358   1443     1095     2706
03-06-18  2706    0      0      2706
04-06-18  2706    0     416     2790
05-06-18  2790   792       291     2791
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the code to pull the date from the spreadsheet instead of forcing in the parameter value.

```
SELECT 
  ILE.[Posting Date] DATE -- <--Change in code
  ,CASE 
    WHEN cast(ILE.Quantity AS NUMERIC(19, 6)) > 0
      AND ILE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom
        AND @DateTo
      THEN cast(ILE.Quantity AS NUMERIC(19, 6))
    ELSE 0
    END AS [In Quantity]
  ,CASE 
    WHEN cast(ILE.Quantity AS NUMERIC(19, 6)) < 0
      AND ILE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom
        AND @DateTo
      THEN - cast(ILE.Quantity AS NUMERIC(19, 6))
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Out Quantity]
  ,(
    SELECT SUM(ILE1.[Quantity])
    FROM [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] AS ILE1
    WHERE ILE1.[Entry No_] = ILE.[Entry No_]
      AND ILE1.[Item No_] = ILE.[Item No_]
      AND ILE1.[Document No_] = ILE.[Document No_]
      AND ILE1.[Posting Date] < @DateFrom
    ) AS [Opening Qty]
  ,(
    SELECT SUM(ILE1.[Quantity])
    FROM [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] AS ILE1
    WHERE ILE1.[Entry No_] = ILE.[Entry No_]
      AND ILE1.[Item No_] = ILE.[Item No_]
      AND ILE1.[Document No_] = ILE.[Document No_]
      AND ILE.[Posting Date] <= @DateTo
    ) AS [Closing Qty]
  ,ILE.[Posting Date] [Posting Date]
  ,ILE.[Item No_] Product
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY [Item No_] ORDER BY ILE.[Posting Date]
    ) Row_Num
INTO #Temp
FROM [Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] ILE
WHERE ILE.[Posting Date] <= @DateTo
  AND ILE.[Primary Customer No_] IN ('MMBP000094 ')

SELECT 
   DATE
  ,Sum([Opening Qty]) [Opening Qty]
  ,Sum([In Quantity]) [In Quantity]
  ,Sum([Out Quantity]) [Out Quantity]
  ,Sum([Closing Qty]) [Closing Qty]
  ,Sum([Opening Qty] + [In Quantity]) [For Billing]
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE -- <--Change in code
```

Comment: How i can do that sir?

Comment: Right  now i have to do Union and add +1 every time

Comment: What dates did you pass in?

Comment: Also, some sample data would be very helpful. Please see these links for how to put that together.    https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/